# How to share same static data objects in Java Web Application?

Tags: java, share

I want to develop a Web browser game in Java (with Struts or Spring) but I have two questions:
- Do you think Java with struts or spring is a good choice? (If no, why?)
- Some configuration data (like the planets and their properties are immutable) should be loaded one time from the database and stay in memory shared by all the requests. What do you recommend for this? Should I put all the configurations data in servlet context?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that you going to create a Spring App, but haven't decided whether to choose Struts or SpringMVC.

I would recommend Spring MVC, mainly because if you are going to be choosing Spring as your container, then you might as well choose Spring MVC, instead of plugging Struts into Spring Container.

About Properties:  Config properties are not something I would NOT store in DB. Instead, I suggest you create *.properties files.

You could have a class with a public static final HashMap.  Also make the Hashmap unmodifiable. Populate that HashMap with the contents of the properties file.

Of course, the better way in a Spring app, would be to create a singleton Spring bean, that loads the properties at initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Struts or Spring good choice ? Yes, both are pretty matured, have huge community, they are open source(if you need can check there code), You should also check out JSF, I personally like Primefaces (JSF component library), GWT or Eclipse RAP are other options available.

Configuration Data in Servlet Context :

Why would you make your servlet context so heavy, you should consider having a cache for such scenario. Have a look at [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) for example.

As per comment:

You can even try creating your own cache to hold your data from DB, something like a Singleton Class holding your data say in a `Map`

Comment: Wouldn't EhCache be an overkill if all we need is local in-memory access for unchanging data?

Comment: Yeah it will be just giving pointer to OP for other caching mechanism other than servlet context.

Comment: It's a good point though, if the data is really large in size, maybe we do need a caching solution such as ehCache, which can(?) persist data to file. From what I understand, it is able to keep most often read data in the memory, rest is sent of to the file system.